# Remote desktop client not available in Win7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. I want to use it to connect to my work computer which has all the necessary configurations done.

So, I type 'Remote desktop connection' in Search from Start Menu but I don't get the Remote Desktop Client application. The search results are shown in the below picture:-

[image]

The top result is the remote desktop connection manager which I downloaded and installed, thinking that it is the client I am looking for. But as it turns out, it is not.

Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Verify the `Windows Feature` is installed

Comment: Is it in your Start menu? Have you refreshed your search index?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007.... I also did a proper search in 'My Computer'...

Comment: @Ramhound....I went to 'Turn Windows Feature On or Off' and checked there... there is no feature named Remote desktop on my Laptop which can be turned on....

Comment: *Is it in your Start menu? Have you refreshed your search index?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `mstsc` via `Win+R`
Or create a shortcut to `C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe`.

Comment: Could someone please tell me why it's downvoted? I had trouble finding the RDP-client in my search-bar, so I just run `mstsc`. For some reason the index has difficulties with finding the right item.

Comment: I didn't down-vote it, but the question was "Why isn't it showing up in my search?", and this answer is "Run this command to start the RDP client".  Based on your question, I can see why someone would find this to be an unsatisfactory answer.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thnx, I guess I overlooked the question because of my own frustration with this issue :)